# Why does MSVC++ require std::setprecision to enable full precision output with std::hexfloat?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As far as I'm aware, the following line is all that is required to output doubles in hex to full precision:

```
std::cout << std::hexfloat << yourDouble << std::endl;
```

But using MSVC++ in Visual Studio 17 this only prints a double to 6 hex-digits. See my code (truncated for clarity):

```
std::ifstream cacheF(pToFile, std::ios::in);
if (!cacheF.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open " << pToFile << "!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

bool readSuccess = true;
unsigned long long sumBegin, cached[2];
double previousTime;
readSuccess = readSuccess && (cacheF >> std::dec >> sumBegin);
readSuccess = readSuccess && (cacheF >> std::hexfloat >> previousTime);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) readSuccess = readSuccess && (cacheF >> std::hex >> cached[i]);

cacheF.close();

if (!readSuccess) {
    std::cerr << "Cache reload failed due to improper file formatting!" << std::endl;
}

std::cout << std::hexfloat << previousTime << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(13) << std::hexfloat << previousTime << std::endl;
```

Input file looks like this:

```
1045644800006
0x1.567be0370cdc8p+7
C6CCFEDA2563B0D1
5E3492440B4BE8B2
```

Output is:

```
0x1.567be0p+7
0x1.567be0370cdc8p+7
```

It's been a while since I last tried this with GCC but if I remember correctly it produced full double precision output without needing setprecision. Can anyone confirm if this is an MSVC++ specific behavior, and if it is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `hexfloat` output should [ignore precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and output the full value, this would be a compiler bug.